# Why does EM radiation travel much further than the magnetic field of an equivalent power electromagnet?

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, wave

If both fall of as 1/r^2 from the source then why can radio waves travel around the world and still be picked up easily at the right frequency but the field from a powerful electromagnet can not?

Comment: The key is *changing* fields propagate as waves, while the electromagnet is constant.

Comment: I understand this concept but I guess I'm still not clear on how that concept allows the wave to be magnitudes stronger at the same distance from the source when they both decay 1/r^2 from the source.

Answer (score 2):

Magnetic fields falls away as the cube of distance [(reference)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Vector_form) but in the presence of an electric field of the correct amplitude and phase, they are much more self-sustaining and fall away individually as 1/R. That makes a huge difference to the distance they can travel.

---

EDIT to avoid confusion by the reader

The power of an EM wave is the electric field multiplied by the magnetic field - therefore, two fields decaying as 1/R produce a power that decays as 1/\$R^2\$

Comment: I can't parse your answer. You seem to be saying that a magnetic field decays more slowly in the presence of an electric field, but that doesn't answer the OP's question about EM radiation.

Comment: @NickJohnson on its own a mag field decays as distance cubed but, the mag field (that is locked into an EM wave) decays as distance. I'm basically just saying what my answer says. Does this version make more sense?

Comment: Where I'm confused is that everything I've read says EM waves decay as 1/r^2 since the area of a sphere expands as 1/r^2 too but you are saying it's 1/r? Is what I have read incorrect? If so, could explain how it decays less? Also, are you saying that in the presence of an E field of the correct ampltude and phase that the magnetic field from a seperate individual electromagnet could itself be extended to decay as only 1/r?

Comment: @LostInPlace - the power of an EM wave does decay with distance squared BUT I'm talking about the fields - they decay as 1/r. To get power both fields are multiplied hence 1/r becomes 1/r^2

Comment: So even if the power of an EM wave decays as quick as the power in the static field of an electromagnet, the EM fields can still be received much further by an antenna than the static magnetic field could be sensed? Or do I still misunderstand?

Comment: A field IS NOT a power so please call it field strength and yes, the fields in an EM wave decay less than an individual E or H fields that are not part of an EM wave.